# Targeting issue when an item is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, dom-events

I have a problem about targeting. I have 5 items. They have own individual values for max and min temperatures in Celsius and Fahrenheit. I have to make them, when I click individual Celsius icon, should change just their value. But now, when I click any Celsius icon, its making changes about all values and they takes the first item's value. You can see it here:

```js
var api_key = "dd39280551e44f1bb34221739171701&q=";
var loc;

$(document).ready(function() {
  // var latitude,longitude;
  

  $.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io', function(d){
    loc = d.loc.split(",");

    var apiLink = "http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.json?key=";
    var days5 = "&days=5";
    var api = apiLink + api_key + loc[0] +','+ loc[1] + days5;


    $.getJSON(api, function(v1) {

   
        var tempSwapForecast = true;


        var forecastdayData = v1.forecast.forecastday;

        var days = forecastdayData.map(function(d) {
          return d.day;
        });

        var maxtempc = days.map(function(maxc) {
          return maxc.maxtemp_c;
        });

        var mintempc = days.map(function(minc) {
          return minc.mintemp_c;
        });

        var maxtempf = days.map(function(maxf) {
          return maxf.maxtemp_f;
        });

        var mintempf = days.map(function(minf) {
          return minf.mintemp_f;
        });


        $('.forecasticons img').each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('src', days[i].condition.icon);
        });

        $('.frc-temp').each(function(i) {
          $(this).html(Math.round(maxtempc[i]) + "-" + Math.round(mintempc[i]));
            $('.frc-degree').click(function() {
              for (var j = 0; j < $(this).length; j++) {
                if(tempSwapForecast===false){
                  $('.frc-temp').html(Math.round(maxtempc[j]) + "-" + Math.round(mintempc[j]));
                  $('.frc-degree').html(" &#8451;");
                  tempSwapForecast = true;
                } else {
                  $('.frc-temp').html(Math.round(maxtempf[j]) + "-" + Math.round(mintempf[j]));
                  $('.frc-degree').html("&#8457;");
                  tempSwapForecast = false;
                }

              }
             

            });



        });


        $('.forecastText').each(function(i) {
          $(this).html(days[i].condition.text);
        });


    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="other-days">
          <div class="forecastday">
            <div class="forecasticons" >
              <img class="fcicon" alt="weather-icon" src="">
            </div>
            <div class="forecastText"></div>
            <div class="forecasttemp">
              <span class="frc-temp"></span>
              <a class="frc-degree" href="#">&#8451;</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="forecastday">
            <div class="forecasticons" >
              <img class="fcicon" alt="weather-icon" src="">
            </div>
              <div class="forecastText"></div>
            <div class="forecasttemp">
              <span class="frc-temp"></span>
              <a class="frc-degree" href="#">&#8451;</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="forecastday">
            <div class="forecasticons" >
              <img class="fcicon" alt="weather-icon" src="">
            </div>
              <div class="forecastText"></div>
            <div class="forecasttemp">
              <span class="frc-temp"></span>
              <a class="frc-degree" href="#">&#8451;</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="forecastday">
            <div class="forecasticons" >
              <img class="fcicon" alt="weather-icon" src="">
            </div>
              <div class="forecastText"></div>
            <div class="forecasttemp">
              <span class="frc-temp"></span>
              <a class="frc-degree" href="#">&#8451;</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="forecastday">
            <div class="forecasticons" >
              <img class="fcicon" alt="weather-icon" src="">
            </div>
              <div class="forecastText"></div>
            <div class="forecasttemp">
              <span class="frc-temp"></span>
              <a class="frc-degree" href="#">&#8451;</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very small changes to make it work: in your click handler, rather than finding by class the field to fill, I use the clicked element to find its parent and then find the class WITHIN that parent. So it becomes $(this).parent().find(...) All these changes are between lines 53 and 59.

```js
var api_key = "dd39280551e44f1bb34221739171701&q=";
var loc;

$(document).ready(function() {
  // var latitude,longitude;


  $.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io', function(d) {
    loc = d.loc.split(",");

    var apiLink = "http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.json?key=";
    var days5 = "&days=5";
    var api = apiLink + api_key + loc[0] + ',' + loc[1] + days5;


    $.getJSON(api, function(v1) {


      var tempSwapForecast = true;


      var forecastdayData = v1.forecast.forecastday;

      var days = forecastdayData.map(function(d) {
        return d.day;
      });

      var maxtempc = days.map(function(maxc) {
        return maxc.maxtemp_c;
      });

      var mintempc = days.map(function(minc) {
        return minc.mintemp_c;
      });

      var maxtempf = days.map(function(maxf) {
        return maxf.maxtemp_f;
      });

      var mintempf = days.map(function(minf) {
        return minf.mintemp_f;
      });


      $('.forecasticons img').each(function(i) {
        $(this).attr('src', days[i].condition.icon);
      });

      $('.frc-temp').each(function(i) {
        // Added a 'units' property, so the temperature
        //  can track what type of unit it is displaying.
        $(this).data("units", "c");
        $(this).html(Math.round(maxtempc[i]) + "-" + Math.round(mintempc[i]));
      });
      $('.frc-degree').on("click", function() {
        // As we use the .frc-temp el often, reference it once.
        var myTempEl = $(this).parent().find(".frc-temp");
        // This is the unique index of the clicked day.
        var myIndex = $(".forecastday").index(
          $(this).parents(".forecastday")
        );
        /****
         * Above, we created a data attribute on the
         *  .frc-temp element to store the units. By
         *  doing this, the element becomes self-
         *  contained. Here, we can toggle the units
         *  based on that data attribute.
         ****/
        if (myTempEl.data("units") === "f") {
          // First, switch the unit attribute...
          myTempEl.data("units", "c");
          // Then, replace the contents of the temp el
          myTempEl.html(
            Math.round(maxtempc[myIndex]) +
            "-" +
            Math.round(mintempc[myIndex]));
          // Then, set the contents of this to 'c'  
          $(this).html(" &#8451;");
          tempSwapForecast = true;
        } else {
          myTempEl.data("units", "f");
          myTempEl.html(
            Math.round(maxtempf[myIndex]) +
            "-" +
            Math.round(mintempf[myIndex]));
          $(this).html("&#8457;");
          tempSwapForecast = false;
        }

      });



      $('.forecastText').each(function(i) {
        $(this).html(days[i].condition.text);
      });


    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="other-days">
    <div class="forecastday">
      <div class="forecasticons">
        <img class="fcicon" alt="weather-icon" src="">
      </div>
      <div class="forecastText"></div>
      <div class="forecasttemp">
        <span class="frc-temp"></span>
        <a class="frc-degree" href="#">&#8451;</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="forecastday">
      <div class="forecasticons">
        <img class="fcicon" alt="weather-icon" src="">
      </div>
      <div class="forecastText"></div>
      <div class="forecasttemp">
        <span class="frc-temp"></span>
        <a class="frc-degree" href="#">&#8451;</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="forecastday">
      <div class="forecasticons">
        <img class="fcicon" alt="weather-icon" src="">
      </div>
      <div class="forecastText"></div>
      <div class="forecasttemp">
        <span class="frc-temp"></span>
        <a class="frc-degree" href="#">&#8451;</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="forecastday">
      <div class="forecasticons">
        <img class="fcicon" alt="weather-icon" src="">
      </div>
      <div class="forecastText"></div>
      <div class="forecasttemp">
        <span class="frc-temp"></span>
        <a class="frc-degree" href="#">&#8451;</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="forecastday">
      <div class="forecasticons">
        <img class="fcicon" alt="weather-icon" src="">
      </div>
      <div class="forecastText"></div>
      <div class="forecasttemp">
        <span class="frc-temp"></span>
        <a class="frc-degree" href="#">&#8451;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

So many many small changes here: the frc-temp elements now have a data attribute that tracks whether the units are farenheit or centigrade, and the way I reference the elements has also changed slightly.

Comment: Hello, thanks its working but with one problem. They have own individual values. But when i click one of them, it takes first item's value. i want every items takes its own value. Sorry i am new on javascript.

Comment: Tracked it back, it was the way the index (either i or j, can't remember which) was being used. Instead, I'm now using the position of the day div within the collection of days to determine the index to use. Also, the tempSwapForecast was causing some odd toggling issues -- I've changed it to store the units on the temp element itself and toggle based on that. Best of luck!

Comment: thank you so much. Its working now. I said i am new on javascript and my ways can be bad sometimes. And thank you for understandable comments too.

Comment: Glad it helped, that's what I'm here for.